Selecting child elements in parent without constantly reselecting parent
I have this code that selects the child element of a parent element:
cy.get('form[data-cy="user_add"]').find('[name="username"]').type('test');

This is working fine as is, but this becomes an issue when I need to constantly select the parent element in order to find the child that I want to type in/modify.
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="username"]').type('testusername');
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="password"]').type('testpassword');
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="repeatpassword"]').type('testpassword');
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="firstname"]').type('testfname');
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="lastname"]').type('testlname');
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="per_station"]').click();
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="per_cashier"]').click();
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').find('[name="per_manage"]').click();

Any suggestions on how to not constantly repeat the selection of the form? Cypress documentation says to not use variables as much as possible due to the async by default nature of it. I also found some documentation on escaping from this async nature and just doing JavaScript code before wrapping it up and doing the assertion after, but I was just wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

I highly recommend following Martin Fowler’s Page Object paradigm. If you do so it will help you with this problem and make your test code a lot less brittle when changes are made to the UI.

@bob Cypress actually suggests that you don't use Page Objects -> https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/03/stop-using-page-objects-and-start-using-app-actions

I’ll need to read that more carefully when I have time. It looks like Cypress recommends calling the API of the code under test to set app state so you can [manipulate the UI in a few specific ways and then] make assertions. Is that correct? If so it feels wrong (I don’t trust the code under test if I’m doing E2E; that’s the whole idea) to me but I guess when in Rome… maybe…?

Use .within() to change the point at which queries start (normally it's <body>).
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').within(($form) => {
  // $form is now the starting point for queries
  cy.get('[name="username"]').type(...)
  cy.get('[name="password"]').type(...)
  ...
})


Agoff's answer is technically correct, but it fails if you want to use the alias across tests because unless you turn off test isolation, you cannot use the alias value in a second test
Using a variable to hold the parent query selector would work multi-test.
const formSelector = 'form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]'

it('tests the form when logged-in', () => {

  cy.get(formSelector).find('[name="username"]').type('testusername')
  ...
})

it('tests the form when not logged in', () => {
  cy.get(formSelector).find('[name="username"]').type('testusername')
  ...
})

Or with templates to inject the parent,
const formSelector = 'form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]'

it('tests the form when logged-in', () => {

  cy.get(`${formSelector} [name="username"]`).type('testusername')
  ...
})

it('tests the form when not logged in', () => {
  cy.get(`${formSelector} [name="username"]`).type('testusername')
  ...
})

The only time it would not work is when one test causes the test window to restart, usually when switching domains from one test to another, say when you need to login via a third-party service.

D.Fagen's answer makes the most sense and is most likely what I would do, given all of your commands are one after another. However, if your commands were not structured that way but instead had other commands, which you did not want to start their queries at the form parent element, you can store the parent as an alias, and reference it a little easier.
cy.get('form[data-cy="manage_users_addform"]').as('form');
// other commands
cy.get('@form').find('[name="username"]').type('testusername');


you can try the then condition also.

cy.get('form[data-cy="user_add"]').then(()=> {
cy.get('[name="username"]').type('testusername');
cy.get('[name="password"]').type('testpassword');
})

if the parent element contains more then 2 

cy.get('form[data-cy="user_add"]').first().within(() => {
cy.get('[name="username"]').type('testusername');
cy.get('[name="password"]').type('testpassword');
})


Why would you use .then()?
